# Apply custom theme to page served by custom module

Tags: magento2

How do I apply a custom theme to a page served from a custom module?

Up to this point I have been using the admin dashboard dialogues to apply custom themes through content > pages.

Am I supposed to be declaring this relationship in a layout page maybe?

I have a custom module `Landing`, which serves up a landing page block with `landing_page.phtml`, but I'd like to apply my custom theme styles to this page. Having a hard time finding any documentation that points to this...